# Using multiple font in next js with tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, google-fonts

I want to use two fonts, one for the whole website and the other for a specific `<h3>` tag. I am using Google fonts. But, unfortunately, it is not working.

The `layout.tsx` file is as follows:

```js
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Nunito_Sans, Tulpen_One } from 'next/font/google'

const nunito_sans = Nunito_Sans({ subsets: ['latin'] })

const tulpen_one = Tulpen_One({
  weight: '400',
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-tulpen',
})

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Name | Portfolio',
  description: 'moto',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={nunito_sans.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

the `tailwind.config.ts` is as follows:

```js
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        cursive: ['var(--font-tulpen)'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

I used it like this:

```html
<h3 className='my-4 text-3xl font-medium tracking-wider font-cursive'>First name <span>Last name</span></h3>
```

But, I am not getting the intended result. How, can I do this?

Comment: you can find the multiple font config here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330857/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-tailwind-css-in-next-js-project/78032739#78032739